# How to perform a SQLite query based on a ForiegnKey field value in sqflite , flutter

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I need to perform a query in a table, filtered based on the value of another table that is being used here as a `ForiegnKey`, here is the structure of the 2 tables:

**The 1st table**

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Shift (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, startTime TEXT, endTime TEXT, employeeName TEXT, branchName TEXT, onDuty BOOLEAN )");
```

**The 2nd Table**

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Balance(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,cashAmount REAL,ccAmount REAL, type TEXT, sihftId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (sihftId) REFERENCES Shift (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ');
```

Now the query I want to perform is something like :

```
'SELECT * FROM Balance WHERE SHIFT__>onDuty = ?'
```

But I don't know what is the correct syntax for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are expecting more from the foreign key than it will deliver.  You still need to join the two tables

```
SELECT * From Balance JOIN Shift ON Balance.sihftId = Shift.id WHERE Shift.onDuty = ?
```